# Nested Enumerations for HTA

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm trying to create an enumeration for a Hierarchical Task Analysis. According to the style I've been given the list needs to look like the following:

To try and demonstrate the indentations clearer (markdown wasn't working very well) I have indicated indents using '-'. The enumerisation is meant to have 0 as the root with 1 and 2 as its children. 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 are all children of 1. Sorry the original question wasn't completely clear.

*Plan 0: 1 then 2*

0 Use SatNav

-1 Select new

--1.1 Chose Postcode

--1.2 Chose City

--1.3 Chose Previous Destination

-2 Chose Mode

However, I can't get LaTeX to display a list in this style where the root is 0 and its children start at 1. Please help.

Here is an example from my lecture notes:
[image: Lecture note example]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you want to:

1. have your enumerations to start from 0 instead of one;
2. have the labels for your enumerations (at least two levels) to end with a parenthesis;
3. have the number nested

I have provided the code below, here some remarks:

- use the package `enumitem` to customize the lists
- the `setlist` instruction allows for the first layer to start from 0
- the renewcommand apply the parenthesis and the "nested numbering".

So here it is:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 %enumitem will manage the enumerations
 \usepackage{enumitem}

 % tells that the enumeration of level 1 (outermost) should start at 0
 \setlist[enumerate,1]{start=0}

 % sets the label for the second level of the enumeration to its counter value
 \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}

 % set the value of the second level counter representation as 
 % 1st level counter followed by "." 
 % followed by the arabic number of the 2nd level, 
 % followed by ")" e.g. 2.1)
 \renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii})}

 % sets the label for the first level of the enumeration to its value followed by ")"
 \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi)} 

 \begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}
   \item Use SatNav
   \item Select new destination
   \begin{enumerate}
     \item Chose Postcode
     \item Chose City
     \item chose Previous Destination
   \end{enumerate}
   \item Chose Mode 
 \end{enumerate}

 \end{document}
```

[image: Here are the results]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[start=0]
       \item Use SatNav
       \item Select new destination
           \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
             \item Chose Postcode
             \item Chose City
             \item chose Previous Destination
           \end{enumerate}
       \item Chose Mode 
    \end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

If you will use a lot nested list with legal style, write in the preamble some like:

```
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.}
```

And then you can use the environment `legal` without optional arguments (i.e., `\begin{legal} \item text ... \end{legal}`).